# Gate Driver Voltage drifting?

Tags: voltage, gate-driving, transducer

I am using below circuit to differentially drive ultrasonic transducer.

[image]

It works almost as expected. However, I notice strange phenomenon if i observe the output at the transducer with dual gate driver with inverting/noninverting output.

[image]

Blue wave is supply voltage(15V) and yellow wave is transducer side of R1. I measured both of them with respect to ground.

I understand that the supply voltage is not doing a good job since it drops almost the same with amplitude of output waveform causing HIGH voltage of the waveform to drop accordingly.

However, I don't understand why the Low(supposed to be 0V) level of the wave form keeps rising? and how i should fix it?

[Addendum] I have added picture showing PCB traces below.

[image]

One that is highlighted as white is power rail. The thickness is 0.4~0.5mm and total length is about 70 mm.

Bottom layer is basically ground plane with some traces going through via.

Comment: What does your power and grounding system look like? Is this on a PCB? If so what are your trace sizes.

Comment: Where do you take your ground reference from? If supply voltage drops due to resistance in the supply cable, I expect ground to rise about the same amount. Measure ground at the driver IC, if you take the ground reference from somewhere else.

Comment: Also could you provide a sheet on the TC442? You need probably have a capacitance problem

Comment: Oh, could you also provide some info on the transducer?

Comment: @laptop2d Power and grounding system is not an optimal because it is double layered PCB with one layer for ground(but allowing some traces through vias). Supply rail come through a trace on top layer.

Comment: @laptop2d http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422G.pdf this is link to the gate driver's datasheet

Comment: @laptop2d I am not sure about the transducer's spec, but i believe it can have up to 800pF with resonance frequency of 1MHz.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher I took the ground reference from near regulator.  I measured the supply voltage near the regulator and near gate driver and the difference was about 0.5V(from 14.9V to 14.4V). So, I think that some voltage drop occurs through the trace's resistance. However, I measured the ground level near the gate driver, but there was no difference between ground level near voltage regulator and near gate driver, probably because ground is done via whole plane of bottom layer.

Comment: Since your transducer has a much lower capacitance than your bypass, I would suspect that you have too much parasitic inductance in your system. A two layer PCB is not the most optimal. If you can provide a picture of the PCB or the trace sizes.

Comment: @laptop2d I've added a picture of PCB if you would like to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one of two problems.
1) Your osciloscope measurement needs to be better. Try putting the ground as close to the source as possible and shorten the leads. There shouldn't be that much indcutance @ 1Mhz, but depending on how you have your grounds, you may be seeing the effects of that.

2)There is a potential to draw a lot of power, up to 5W at a 0.34 Amp load. IF you don't have a good grounding\power system, its going to take a beating. It won't be able to keep up with the load at that speed. Your load\transducer must be highly capacitive because it is drawing down your supply voltage (assuming that you have a good measurement). Since I don't know what the rest of your design looks like, it might be a good idea to parallel some caps and see if it helps the power draw down problem. This will help for two reasons. Each cap also has parasitic inductance and resistance, paralleling them (in short) will help minimize that effect. You will also get more capacitance, which will also help.

Did you know you can [calculate the parasitic inductance](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=util_inductance_trace_g)? You will need to do some estimation. I've drawn a simplified circuit with parasitic's. LT spice is a good tool for doing a reality check. You can also run some calcs by hand by simplifying the circuit (the lower circuit I've drawn). Then add the parasitic's back one at a time and see if any of them are hurting you. Some can be ignored, like the trace resistance R5 and R6 are in series with each other, if the trace is 10mΩ going to make a difference when added to 22.1? Probably not. I could go on and on, but a great resource is a book called [Electromagnetic Compatability Engineering](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470189304.html) by Henry W. Ott, it goes into great detail on parasitic's.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL4CWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You mean parallel capacitor with the bypass capacitor of gate driver?

Comment: Yes, if its an smt device, just stack a few of them on top of each other.

Comment: Assuming you have FR4 and 1oz copper, your top trace will have 1-2uH and 10mΩ of resistance. With that much inductance you are basically turning your power circuit into and LRC (see above simplified circuit) and the resonance point is close to the freqency of your signal. What can you do? Adding capacitors will help but your best bet is lowering the inductance. Cut the trace and get a nice thick wire and run it across your board.

Comment: I can not cut the trace length. Would moving the regulator nearer to the driver do the same job?

Comment: Yes that would help also. You don't have to cut the whole thing, just a few mills to disconnect it. If you find it doesn't work you can solder a jumper wire to it. Moving the regulator should also help. Speaking of the regulator, it has an impedance also, you may want to look at that and see if there is any info on recovery or 'speed' of the amplifier.